# Laravel 5.3 -- Trying to check a checkbox in a dynamic list

Tags: laravel

I have a collection on my user object named prefs which contains a collection named auctions. When I dump my user, I can confirm it as such

```
prefs: {
       auctions: {
          A320: false,
          A330: true,
          A340: true,
          B737CL: true,
          B737NG: true,
          B747: true,
          B757: true,
          B767: true,
          B777: true,
         Regional: true,
         Expendables: true,
         Miscellaneous: true
    }
}
```

I am trying to check checkboxes in a list of categories that are dynamically created (an admin can add more as needed) with the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{$cat->cat}}" name="categories[]" value="{{$cat->id}}" {{($user->prefs->auctions->$cat->cat ? 'checked' : '')}}>
```

I am getting

```
ErrorException in 17b600b2cf36de6dc2af6eb299cce5a13d6e20e0.php line 33:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$auctions (View: /Users/jgravois/Documents/Code/_work/uaminc.com/resources/views/Members/Auction/index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wrong in:

```
$user->prefs->auctions->$cat->cat
```

Are you sure you do not want to do:

```
$user->prefs->auctions->{$cat->cat}
```

In this last code $cat->cat is calculated first, else ->cat come at the end.

Warning: a JSON dump don't tell you what is an object or an array. To know that, you need a PHP dump such the ones returned by `var_dump`.

If `prefs` is an array, you will have to do:

```
$user->prefs['auctions'][$cat->cat]
```

Comment: I made that change which made perfect sense to me but the error remains. I also tried $user->prefs['auctions']->{$cat->cat} but that gave me a trying to get something from an object error.

Comment: if prefs and auctions are array, you must do `$user->prefs['auctions'][$cat->cat]` and if $cat is also an array: `$user->prefs['auctions'][$cat['cat']]`

Comment: according to the dump in original question, both are objects but I tried both of these and the first one worked perfectly.

Comment: If `[]`, it means it have translated into an array somewhere after your dump. But your dump is JSON (no distinction between arrays and objects), for a more precise dump, you should use the PHP `var_dump`, I edit the answer to explain all that.